# Reference paper and/or books about spatial data analysis, possibly bayesian

Tags: self-study, bayesian, spatial

It is for my master thesis, I need to go more in depth.
Any suggestion about recent works is really welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book I have is [Hierarchical Modeling and Analysis for Spatial Data](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/158488410X) by Banerjee, Carlin, and Gelfand. It's used in the spatial statistics course at the University of Minnesota where two of the authors are located. It starts out with the classical basics and then moves toward Bayesian methods in later chapters. One caveat is that, being over ten years old, the computing examples are a mix of R and S-plus, and an updated (all R) edition is in the works and expected soon.

Comment: It is the same I have, can I ask you for a list of papers or where to look for important contributes in the area? I have a problem of geostatistics and the only solution I can think of is trivial and I have already implemented everything I could think of. Not sure it is enough for a Master Thesis and my tutor is not really collaborative. Thanks for your help.

Comment: +1 - I'd also suggest the work and books of [Noel Cressie](http://www.stat.osu.edu/~ncressie/) - especially his newer one on spatio-temporal data. That should be enough reading for a few years I would reckon for most people.